# libiconv-2.dll error while playing video in OpenCV

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, video, libiconv

I tried to play a video using OpenCV-2.4.7 in Visual Studio 2010, Win 7

Code is as follow-

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    cvNamedWindow( "Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "C:/Users/17/Desktop/Wildlife.avi" );
    IplImage* frame;

    while(1) {
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if( !frame ) break;
        cvShowImage( "Window", frame );
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if( c == 27 ) break;
    }
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Window" );
}
```

Debugs is fine but on running, a waring window opens saying **"The program can't start because libiconv-2.dll is missing from your computer"**.

I tried to download libiconv-2.dll into system package then it showed the error **"C:\Windows\System32\libiconv-2.dll', Binary was not built with debug information".**

Is there any possible missing setting?? what should be done to run this code?

Comment: I am confused as to why your program is trying to link to libiconv in the first place; it is a GNU dll and it's required only when you are using the gcc compiler. Are you project setting correct.? Have you used CMake to generate the project files?

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with opencv_ffmpeg247.dll in the latest release (2.4.7) as [described here](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3400)

I'm having the same issue, though with the fix earmarked for 2.4.8 I'd suggest either installing an earlier version (2.4.6) or using the latest copy from the [repo here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/3rdparty/ffmpeg)

Comment: I installed version 2.4.6 and now having this error-
    C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\bin\opencv_ffmpeg246.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.